# Unity 3d won't import composite animated characters properly?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 3d, 3dsmax, fbx

I've been working with a few 3ds max models which have some facial expressions  animated with Composite materials (controlling opacity on certain frames, so the character goes from an idle eye texture to a blinking eye texture). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when importing them as .fbx on Unity 3D, textures won't change at all so the character show's up with his base static texture during all the animation length .

Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: When importing the character itself is there problems with the textures? or   is it only when you import its animations?

Comment: The only problem with the textures was a minor color change, but that's all.